# Remove form submit button and replace with loading gif

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have a form with a submit button and would like to remove the button and replace it with a loading gif image. **I don't want this to happen just on click**, since the form is verified **I want the button to disappear only when all input fields are correctly filled** so that the gif image shows progress. How can I do this?

Note: This is not a event to fire on success either, I want it to be a progress indicator. On success the form fade and display a message: "Thanks for contacting us! We will get back to you very soon..." and the jQuery below already handles this.

Here is the php code:

```
<?php

// Email address verification
function isEmail($email) {
    return preg_match('|^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]{2,})+$|i', $email);
};

if($_POST) {

    // Enter the email where you want to receive the message
    $emailTo = 'example@gmail.com';

    $clientName = addslashes(trim($_POST['name']));
    $clientEmail = addslashes(trim($_POST['email']));
    $number = addslashes(trim($_POST['number']));
    $message = addslashes(trim($_POST['message']));

    $subject = 'Query from My Domain';

    $sendMessage = 'Hi' . "\n\n";
    $sendMessage .= $message . "\n\n";
    $sendMessage .= 'From: ' . $clientName . "\n";
    $sendMessage .= 'Email: ' . $clientEmail . "\n";
    $sendMessage .= 'Contact number: ' . $number . "\n";

    $array = array();
    $array['nameMessage'] = '';
    $array['emailMessage'] = '';
    $array['numberMessage'] = '';
    $array['messageMessage'] = '';

    if($clientName == '') {
        $array['nameMessage'] = 'Please enter your full name.';
    }
    if(!isEmail($clientEmail)) {
        $array['emailMessage'] = 'Please insert a valid email address.';
    }
    if($number == '') {
        $array['numberMessage'] = 'Please enter a valid contact number.';
    }
    if($message == '') {
        $array['messageMessage'] = 'Please enter your message.';
    }
    if($clientName != '' && isEmail($clientEmail) && $message != '') {
    // Send email
    $headers = "From: " . $clientName . ' <' . $clientEmail . '>' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= PHP_EOL;
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0".PHP_EOL;
    $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;".PHP_EOL;
    $headers .= " boundary=\"boundary_sdfsfsdfs345345sfsgs\"";
    mail($emailTo, $subject, $sendMessage, $headers);
    }

    echo json_encode($array);

}   else {
        header ('location: index.html#contact');
}

?>
```

and here is the jQuery:

```
// Contact form
$('.contact-form form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var form = $(this);
    var nameLabel = form.find('label[for="contact-name"]');
    var emailLabel = form.find('label[for="contact-email"]');
    var numberLabel = form.find('label[for="contact-number"]');
    var messageLabel = form.find('label[for="contact-message"]');

    nameLabel.html('Full name');
    emailLabel.html('Email');
    numberLabel.html('Contact number');
    messageLabel.html('Message');

    var postdata = form.serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'sendmail.php',
        data: postdata,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json) {
            if(json.nameMessage !== '') {
                nameLabel.append(' - <span class="red error-label"> ' + json.nameMessage + '</span>');
            }
            if(json.emailMessage !== '') {
                emailLabel.append(' - <span class="red error-label"> ' + json.emailMessage + '</span>');
            }
            if(json.numberMessage !== '') {
                numberLabel.append(' - <span class="red error-label"> ' + json.numberMessage + '</span>');
            }
            if(json.messageMessage !== '') {
                messageLabel.append(' - <span class="red error-label"> ' + json.messageMessage + '</span>');
            }
            if(json.nameMessage === '' && json.emailMessage === '' && json.numberMessage === '' && json.messageMessage === '') {
                form.fadeOut('fast', function() {
                    form.parent('.contact-form').append('<h2 class="text-center"><span class="orange">Thanks for contacting us!</span> We will get back to you very soon.</h2>');
                });
            } 
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: what is not working?

Comment: each time you validate an email address with a regex, a kitten dies. https://davidcel.is/posts/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/ Seriously. Don't.

Comment: I tried adding '$(function(){
         $(".btn-default").click(function(e){
             $(this).replaceWith('<img src="/images/loading.gif" />');
             console.log(this);
             $('contact-form').submit();
         });
     });' but the button disappear on click even ifs the required fields are not completed...

Answer (score 0):

do an ajax .done() after your ajax call to replace the button back